# Clear the session in delete popup at mobile view

Tags: angular

[image]

Once we enter the password for delete operation it gets deleted and again after entering the password for delete another field with the same password is shown again.

```
<button type="button"
class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm icmn-bin"
[data-toggle="modal" data-name="{{source_info.source.name}}" 
[attr.data-target]="'#delete_modal_' + source_info.source.name"  (click)="password=''"
*ngIf="source_info.source.assigned ===  false"
></button>
```

Comment: but once the page get refreshed the password will gone

Comment: question is not so cleared to understand

Comment: i mentioned in screenshot..plz see that when i click the delete icon the popup will open and we have to enter password then only we can delete that particular field this is our bussiness but in my case the field will delete properly but when i click next field delete icon it will showing the password automatically.....hope u understand